# I would like to learn here about tenses

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it correct to ask someone that

*May I have a contact number of Jimmy's dad who **fell down** in the party last night.* or *May I have a contact number of Jimmy's dad **who felt/fall down** in the party last night*

Comment: Felt? _Felt_ is the past tense of a completely different verb _feel_. It has nothing to do with _fall_.

Comment: I guess the OP wanted to ask the difference between **fall/fell** and **had fallen**.

Answer (score 2):

Fall down means : to fall to the ground. The past form is " fell down".

Feel means : to experience something physical or
emotional. The past form is "felt ".

That's why the correct answer of your sentence should be " May I have a contact number of Jimmy's dad who fell down
in the party last night. ".

Comment: Shouldn't it be _during the party_?